# Heatmap of a correlation matrix

Tags: r

I want to create a heatmap of a correlation matrix of size 3*3. Each box of the heatmap represent the absolute value of a correlation. I have to use a colour gradient to represent the absolute value of the correlation : for the absolute value of the correlation from 0 to 0.75, I have to use a red colour gradient ; for the absolute value of the correlation from 0.75 to 0.85, I have to use a yellow colour gradient ; for the absolute value of the correlation from 0.85 to 1, I have to use a green colour gradient. I think I can use the ggplot function to create this heatmap. However, I do not manage to do the colour gradient and I need help to create this heatmap with this colour gradient.

Comment: What have you tried? Provide example data. See some manuals: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/215-the-heatmap-function.html and https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/79-levelplot-with-ggplot2.html

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I create the heatmapMatCor function which enables us to create the heatmap.
The mat_cor_comp parameter is the correlation matrix.

```
heatmapMatCor <-function(mat_cor_comp,
                         limit = c(0, 1),
                         midpoint = 0.8)
{
names_blocks = rownames(mat_cor_comp)
vec_cor_comp = as.vector(abs(mat_cor_comp))
data_comp = data.frame(block1 = rep(names_blocks, dim(mat_cor_comp)[2]),
                         block2 = rep(names_blocks,
                                      each =    dim(mat_cor_comp)[1]),
                         value = vec_cor_comp)
  
ggplot(data = data_comp, aes(block1, block2, fill = value))+
geom_tile(color = "white")+
scale_colour_gradient2(low = "blue", high = "red", mid = "yellow",
                           midpoint = midpoint, limits = limit,
                           name="Pearson\nCorrelation") +
theme_minimal()+
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1,
                                     size = 12, hjust = 1))+
coord_fixed()
  

}
```